# Cannot find handler 'org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleRequest' in project

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, aws-lambda

I am trying to run/debug a lambda application locally but my intellij keeps giving this error.

My AWS Lambda configuration looks like ->
[image]

Error in Intellij :
[image]

I am using springboot 3.1, java 17 and using the springframework.cloud dependency in my gradle file.
`implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws', version: '3.+'`

I am following this doc to create the lambda application-> https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/aws.html

Is there any missing configuration?  What am I doing wrong here? :(

Answer (score 1):

This post just tends to be something that helps but not fully solve your problem.

I tried this tutorial https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2022/02/aws-in-intellij-idea/#lambda and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/create-new-lambda.html but choose Java for the project. After creation, the class is a bit different from Spring's sample:

```
package helloworld;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent;

/**
 * Handler for requests to Lambda function.
 */
public class App implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(final APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input, final Context context) {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("X-Custom-Header", "application/json");

        APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                .withHeaders(headers);
        try {
            final String pageContents = this.getPageContents("https://checkip.amazonaws.com");
            String output = String.format("{ \"message\": \"hello world\", \"location\": \"%s\" }", pageContents);

            return response
                    .withStatusCode(200)
                    .withBody(output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return response
                    .withBody("{}")
                    .withStatusCode(500);
        }
    }

    private String getPageContents(String address) throws IOException{
        URL url = new URL(address);
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
            return br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the run dialog:

[image]

So I think your project should input **Handler** like `example.FunctionConfiguration`, however, I can't build the spring sample project successfully as I'm really new to AWS Lamda, and there are some errors in the log.

Answer (score 0):

This is AWS Toolkit for IntelliJ's problem. The plugin is only accepting the handler if it is in your project source root. so you can't use Spring Cloud Function's `handleRequest`.

To solve that, as answered above, you need to implement or extend requestHandler. For example :

```
public class HandlerWrapper extends FunctionInvoker{
    public void invokerWrapper(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
        this.handleRequest(input, output, context);
    }
}
```

Then set `HandlerWrapper::invokerWrapper` as a handler.